# Twitter Error Code 400 when tweeting an emoji

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I know that my authentication is working and I can make tweets just fine. I have no reason to believe that the tweepy library is causing this problem, though I suppose I have no reason to rule it out. My code looks something like this, attempting to tweet an emoji flag. No other emoji is working either.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.twitter['consumer_key'], keys.twitter['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(keys.twitter['access_token'], keys.twitter['access_token_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print('Connected to the Twitter API...')
api.update_status(r'testing \U0001F1EB\U0001F1F7')
```

I get an [error code 400](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) with seemingly no additional info about what the reason is. Trying to determine if the problem is the encoding in the string is somehow wrong, or if it is simply some sort of problem with sending it to Twitter's API.

Answer (score 0):

You have unicode in your string. Because you are using Python 2 use:

```
api.update_status(u"testing \U0001F1EB\U0001F1F7")
```

Notice that I changed r"x" to u"x".

If you are using Python 3, you can just use:

```
api.update_status("testing \U0001F1EB\U0001F1F7")
```

Update: This is the tweet that I sent using this code:

https://twitter.com/twistedhardware/status/686527722634383360